# web apache redirect request to index.html

Tags: flutter, apache, web, single-page-application

I have built a site with Flutter Web that has generated a single-page app. It is deployed on the server and works fine (https://www.tg1s.com).

But, I need to access some "pages" directly via the Url. In order to do that I need to redirect all requests to index.html.

I tried with a .htaccess file placed beside the index.html file with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Then, I refresh my page (that was working fine) and I receive an error "500 Internal server error". I also tried several variation of the code but always with the same result.
The site is hosted by OVH.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Increase your LogLevel to trace8, restart, retest.  It will show you exactly what is going on, in your error log file.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !
The error came from the text editor used to write the .htaccess file.
I used TextEdit (macOs) and the resulting file was bugged. I tried with Atom and it works fine.